# Does Window's CMD.exe support exec?

Tags: windows, cmd

We'd like to run a program from CMD.exe, but to replace CMD.exe with the new process. What we're seeing is that CMD will always spawn any program as a subprocess, but we need CMD to invoke a specific subprocess, and replace itself with this process.  In POSIX, you'd accomplish this with `execl*()/execv*()` family of functions.

I'm aware of the START command, but this command opens a new console -- which is not an option for us.  Our process is being run from within a service and cannot open a new console. We are looking for a way to ask CMD.exe to invoke `exec()` type functionality.

NOTE: Our research says this CANNOT be done, but before we give up, I thought I'd check with others.

Comment: Not possible, sorry. Why do you need to go through `cmd` to spawn your process?

Comment: We need to run a python script -- and that script performs os.execl() -- but because CMD.exe stays loaded it sees the python process end and re-injects itself into processing stdin/stdout.

Comment: You don't need `cmd` to run a Python script.  Just run python.exe (or whatever) directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to [Serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/315077/is-there-a-windows-cmd-equivalent-of-unix-shells-exec)

There is a full answer regarding your question.
It is possible for batch scripts with "call" but not for processes / programs

Comment: Sad -- but I suspect your right.  Thanks for the ServerFault link.